# Apple rejected the app due to "Token mismatch" authentication error in a Flutter app with Firebase Phone Authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, apple-push-notifications

Firebase Authentication with phone number is configured and tested on iOS via Testflight but seems that is not working when Apple is reviewing the app.

We provided a whitelisted phone number which worked with the build downloaded from Testflight.
I've found a couple of similar issues in GitHub but all was fixed... I'm using the latest version of Firebase auth plugin.

I added a GitHub issue as well but no reaction there: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3800

Did somebody had to deal with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the app passed Apple review. Below is what we did, in case somebody will encounter this in the future:

- We had two APN's created in Apple Developer account. The second one was configured in Firebase Console

  ```
   ===> we removed the first so now we have only one APN in Apple Dev account
  ```
- In Firebase Console we had also certificates uploaded (Firebase states that
  those are not used if a .p8 key is uploaded)

  ```
   ===> we removed the unused APN certificate and used only the APN .p8 key.
  ```

Resubmitted the app to review and it passed.

Answer (score 0):

I try many times, and I changed APNs but nothing works, I try to remove the appcheck library, so that fix it.